# Do we have different vCard and vCalendar specification properties for Android, IOS and MS Outlook?

Tags: vcf-vcard, vcalendar

I got many properties for vCard @ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VCard

e.g.

```
BEGIN:VCARD
VERSION:3.0
PRODID:-//Apple Inc.//iOS 6.0.1//EN
N:;Test;;;
FN:Test
TEL;type=CELL;type=VOICE;type=pref:+1XXXXXXXXXX
TEL;type=WORK;type=VOICE:+1XXXXXXXXXXX
REV:2012-12-17T21:01:31Z
END:VCARD
BEGIN:VCARD
```

Here I would like to know is there any operating system specific properties are there or not. Means in above example we have PRODID property. How I'll get know that this property is supported by all operating system. Is there any clue to know few of properties not supported by Android, IOS or MS Outlook.

Answer (score 1):

You won't find any up to date table listing all versions of all OS (and all clients on each OS), along with the properties supported by each.

If you look at https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2426#section-4 , only the VERSION, FN and N property are mandatory.
PRODID is very likely to be present as well.

vCard 4 (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6350) has a cardinality for each property but most clients still use vCard 3 and in any case, that will not really address your OS related question either.